# Missing index details for procedure in SQL Server

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have stored procedure having two select statement combined with union all operator. Each select statement contains five left joins with views. The select performance is very slow. Each table contains 10 million records.

Is there any way (query or any other method) to find missing index details for the stored procedure?

Comment: Execute the procedure in SSMS. Before you execute, click the `include actual query plan` button. Enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing index details, if any, are included in the stored procedure execution plan. The actual or estimated plan can be viewed from SSMS (Query menu options) or retrieved from cache using the query below.

```
SELECT query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS ps
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ps.plan_handle)
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'YourDatabase.dbo.YourProcedure');
```